# How can I go about setting up push notifications using firebase cloud messaging and cloud functions?

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm been coding for a year now and know swift really well and the basics to javascript. I've built a social media like app and its completely done besides the push notification functionality... which  i've been struggling with for quite a while now.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement these in order to send notifications like when a user follows another user or they receive a new messege.

I don't understand how to integrate the cloud functions that I would write using and node.js with my xcode project.

When I look for documentation online its usually just how to send push notifications using the firebase notifications console which is cool but doesn't trigger based off specific user actions or events (ex: when the user gets a new follower)

I think since im struggling with grasping the concept of how to implement it, the actual technical set up of it makes even less sense. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: For an example of sending a message through the FCM API, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, what you have to do is set up server-side processing of your database to manage when events occur. This is what the Node.js code will be. Everything is connected through the database-- your Xcode and Node.js code work independently, but both communicate with Firebase. You can create a Cloud Function that will automatically run when it detects changes in your database, and this will automatically send push notifications.

I've done a similar project-- I set up a listener for my Realtime Database in my Cloud Function. Every time the user got a new follower, i.e. their followers tree was updated, I sent a notification to the device using an FCM token (which I also stored in the database).

```
exports.onTimeEnd = functions.database.ref("users/{user}/followers")
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  // your code here
}
```

In that block, you can call a `.once()` to find out the user's token to send them a notification with.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

This link here told me everything I had to do in regards to set up in the terminal. Super helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I figured this out! Would this set up support an app that had a large user base like 100,000 for example? Since the node.js code is independent does their need to be any maintenance work done to it when gaining more users?